# How to round numbers to million, thousand, hundred, 1, 0.1, 0.01 and so on? possibly in JS?

Tags: javascript, math, formula

is there any mathematical formula for this kind of rounding?
example:

```
1,234,567 → 1,000,000
9,321,232 → 1,000,000

12,230 → 10,000
90,000 → 10,000

1,234 → 1,000
9,000 → 1,000

9 → 1

0.12321 → 0.1
0.9123 → 0.1

0.01321 → 0.01
0.09321 → 0.01

and so on
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the most significant digit with log base 10 floored, then raise 10 to that power.

```js
const nums = [
  1_234_567,
  9_321_232,
  12_230,
  90_000,
  1_234,
  9_000,
  9,
  0.12321,
  0.9123,
  0.01321,
  0.09321,
];

const weirdRound = (n) => 10 ** (Math.floor(Math.log10(n)));

console.log(nums.map(weirdRound));
```

Comment: amazing! thank you very much! just wonder why is the number separated by _ and it still works?

Comment: @bbnn I manually added them. In javascript (and a lot of other languages), an underscore `_` is able to be used to represent a spacer in the number, since commas mean something else syntactically

Comment: I see! thank you very much. but for some reason when I tried `Math.log10("1_111_222")` it gives me NaN.

Comment: @bbnn That's because when you have a string, javascript doesn't recognize the underscore as a valid character. If you explicitly call `Number("1_111_222")` or `+"1_111_222"` you'll get `NaN`, if you use `parseInt("1_111_222")` you're get `1` because it reads up until the first invalid character. From my knowledge, the underscore separator is only valid when writing a literal number like `1_111_222` not a string that represents a number like `"1_111_222"`

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. I just noticed that you put 1_234_567 not "1_234_567"